# Delete from two tables in one statement

Tags: java, sql, derby

I want to be able to remove all data from 2 tables where the id of a user = the id given. I am using Java, Derby DB, Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 and OS X Mountain Lion.

I have two tables (sorry about the huge image):

[image]

This is my statement so far:

```
String stmt2 = "DELETE FROM APP.PERSON JOIN APP.DATAVAULT WHERE PID = ?";                    
PreparedStatement ps2 = Main.getPreparedStatement(stmt2);
ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(stmt2);
ps2.setInt(1, user.getId());
ps2.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Deleted");
```

I don't understand how I delete from APP.DATAVAULT as well as APP.PERSON. As you can see there is a foreign key within APP.DATAVAULT which is a users id.

I have tried many things such as:

```
String stmt2 = "DELETE FROM APP.PERSON, APP.DATAVAULT WHERE PID = ?";
```

and

```
String stmt2 = "DELETE FROM APP.PERSON AND APP.DATAVAULT WHERE PID = ?";
```

I understand that I must use the foreign key to delete from both, but I don't know how.

Comment: I don't think you can delete from multiple tables using single query, you may need to use multiple delete queries and wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: @Aiias - I don't think these are the same questions. Mine is a Java PreparedStatement not an SQL query/command.

Comment: @PradeepSimha - I did that already but didn't really like it, thought there might have been a better solution.

Comment: @Aiias: This is not a dupe, since that question is for MySQL

Comment: @JohnVasiliou, but you cannot just do it in single statement. You need to use transactions if you want to do multiple delete statements in atomic way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, per [the docs](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/index.html), you cannot delete multiple tables with a single SQL query in Derby.

You *can* with some other RDBMS packages, such as [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)... just not Derby.